# String comparison with Extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a string that has the value `Sam, Mathews, Perry`. I need to know how to see if the string `Perry` is there in the String. How can i do this;

My code as follows, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I need help to solve this.

```
var stringNames= "Sam, Mathews, Perry";

if (stringNames.contains ('Perry')) {
 // 
console.log('Perry found');

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Ext, you can't just make up method names.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

```
var names = 'Sam, Mathews, Perry';
if (names.indexOf('Perry') > -1) {
    console.log('Perry found');
}
```